# Can't get Spring security "remember me" feature to work

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm new to Spring and Java. Trying to set up security [remember me](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) feature.

Here is my `security.xml` and `login.jsp` files. What am I doing wrong?

### `security.xml`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createplayer" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/players" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll"/>

        <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"/>

        <security:remember-me key="MyAppKey" remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
                              remember-me-cookie="remember-me"
                              token-validity-seconds="604800"
                              data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### `login.jsp`

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>

   <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
    Login failed. Check if username or password are correct!
    </c:if>

    <form action = "/login", method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

    Name <br>
    <input name="username"/> <br>
    Password<br>
    <input type="password" name="password"/> <br>

    Remember me <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me">

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit"> <br><br>

</form>

    <h2>${msg}</h2>
    <br>
    <a href = "http://localhost:9999/createaccount"> Create account </a> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

---

P.S. I tried adding

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

to `web.xml` to check if "remember me" works, but instead it "remembering me" it always logs out in one minute.

Answer (score 1):

Add **id** to your jdbc-user-service

```
<security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="jdbcUserService/>
```

and refer to your service from remember-me by it's id like this:

```
<security:remember-me key="MyAppKey"
                      user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately the issue wasn't fixed